# Open a Word process by invoking a .docx

Tags: windows, go

As in the title, I need to open a Word process by invoking via a .docx file. Using `cmd`, I can type `test.docx` and the file is then open in Word immediately. However, if I use

```
cmd := exec.Command(`test.docx`)
err := cmd.Start()
if err != nil {
     log.Fatalln(err)
}
```

The word process is not started. Instead, I receive an error:

> fork/exec .\test.docx: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

I've also tried

```
cmd := exec.Command(`cmd.exe`, `\C`, `start`, `.\test.docx`)
```

but it doesn't work, either.

Is there anyway to do this? I'd be very appreciated for any help

Comment: Try `exec.Command(\`open\`, \`.\test.docx\`)`. From hazy memory of my Windows days, no guarantees that it'll work :)

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the suggestion, but it seems like windows does not have `open` command

Comment: Sorry for haven't provided information for the second case. Both `start` and `open` does not work. I receive this message instead: `exec: "open": executable file not found in %PATH%`

Answer (score 0):

I've investigate a little bit more and have found a solution, using PowerShell instead. However, this is only valid for systems that have PowerShell (of course)

```
cmd_instance := exec.Command("powershell.exe", "Start-Process", "-FilePath", `.\test.docx`, "-WindowStyle", "Hidden")
    if err := cmd_instance.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
```

By using this, I can call a Word process without invoking a PowerShell terminal.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know "Go" language, but, if you can call the MS Word absolute path, could you try this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE" 'C:\Support\File.docx'
```

In PowerShell, i call like that:

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE" 'C:\Support\File.docx'
```

Comment: What if users have a 64-bit Office, or another version than 16, or have it installed in another location? This is not the way.

Comment: Sorry, it's just a example... Maybe if the MS Office path were declared in System Variable %PATH%...